# Initialization of an array of structure initializes all member of a single element, why?

Tags: c, arrays, syntax, initialization, structure

Why would someone do this? Better yet how does this even work? I would have assumed this would somehow create an array of three structures with only the first member defined. I realize a pointer points to the first element of the array, and I see how this could work but how this is defined is throwing me off! (gcc 4.8.4)

```
void do_something(const void *);

typedef struct{

int a;
char b;
int c;

} the_data_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   the_data_t my_data[] = {10, 'a', 30};
   do_something((const void *)my_data);
}

void do_something(const void *data)
{
   printf("data a: %d\ndata b: %c\ndata c: %d\n", ((the_data_t*)data)->a,
      ((the_data_t*)data)->b, ((the_data_t*)data)->c);
}
```

**Output**

> data a: 10
>  data b: a
>  data c: 30

Regardless, I changed it to this..

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   the_data_t my_data = {10, 'a', 30};
   do_something(&my_data);
}
```

Comment: You should show the real code. It can be that the auxiliary function is designed to work with arrays. So if an array contains even one element you should declare it as an array instead of a single structure.

Comment: There's no way to initialise only part of a struct, it's all or nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *I would have assumed this would somehow create an array of three structures with only the first member defined*

No, it's not that way. Basically it creates an array of one element, with all the members intialized.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no
>   designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according
>   to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure
>   members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union. [...]

and

> Each designator list begins its description with the current object associated with the
>   closest surrounding brace pair. Each item in the designator list (in order) specifies a
>   particular member of its current object and changes the current object for the next
>   designator (if any) to be that member.<sup>150)</sup> The current object that results at the end of the
>   designator list is the subobject to be initialized by the following initializer.

and

> [...] If the initializer of
>   a subaggregate or contained union begins with a left brace, the initializers enclosed by
>   that brace and its matching right brace initialize the elements or members of the
>   subaggregate or the contained union. Otherwise, only enough initializers from the list are
>   taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate or the first member of
>   the contained union; [...]

Basically, your code should *ideally* look like

```
the_data_t my_data[] = {{10, 'a', 30}};
```

to visualize initializing *one* element.

OTOH, what you expected may be achieved by

```
 the_data_t my_data[] = {{10}, {'a'}, {30}};
```

where it creates an array of 3 elements, all having the member variable `a`  initialized.

---

That said,

```
 the_data_t my_data[] = {{10, 'a', 30}};
```

is equivalent to writing

```
 the_data_t my_data = {10, 'a', 30};
```

except the part, `my_data` will not be an array anymore (*but what good is an one element array, in general, either?*).

Comment: "what good is an one element array, in general," --> It allows code to pass by "reference"  [GMP example](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2008-March/003085.html)  Research how `mpz_t` is declared.

Comment: This answer is essentially correct, but it would be a lot clearer if it also cited C2011 6.7.9/20, which explicitly describes the semantics for the case where there are no braces around a member's initializer, as is observed here.

Answer (score 3):

Compiler will treat

```
the_data_t my_data[] = {10, 'a', 30};
```

as

```
the_data_t my_data[1] = {{ 10, 'a', 30 }}; // Though it will raise warning.
```

So, `my_data` is an array of one `the_data_t` type.

This is similar to when a two dimensional array is declared like this

```
int a[][3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

then compiler will treat it as

```
int a[1][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 } };
```

Print the size of `a` and you will get `12` (if size of `int` is `4` on that machine).

Comment: Clearly the particular compiler in use *does* interpret the initializer as you describe, but I'm having trouble seeing how that behavior is described by the standard.

Comment: @JohnBollinger; This is described in section **6.7.9/20**: *If the initializer of a subaggregate or contained union begins with a left brace, the initializers enclosed by that brace and its matching right brace initialize the elements or members of the subaggregate or the contained union. Otherwise, only enough initializers from the list are taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate or the first member of the contained union; any remaining initializers are left to initialize the next element or member of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate or [...].*

Answer (score 2):

It's not proper.  GCC will give you a warning for this:

```
warning: missing braces around initializer
warning: (near initialization for ‘my_data[0]’)
```

What it will do is create a 1 element array.

Comment: GCC does warn, and I agree with it and with you that omitting the braces around member initializers is poor style.  But that's *all* it is.  The code is perfectly proper in the sense that it conforms to the standard.

Answer (score 2):

gcc will give you warning about this issue, if you use the warning switch.

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:14:25: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
 the_data_t my_data[] = {10, 'a', 30};
                        ^
test.c:14:25: note: (near initialization for ‘my_data’)
$
```

To fix this either you can properly initialize the array as:

```
the_data_t my_data[] = {{10, 'a', 30}};
```

Or, as you showed in the post, you can change `my_data` to a struct variable.

```
the_data_t my_data = {10, 'a', 30}; // And call do_something as
do_something((const void *)&my_data);
```